# Can VLAN traffic pass through an ASA?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

Let's say I had the topology L3Switch1 -> ASA -> L3Switch2

Is it possible for the ASA to pass VLAN information to L3Switch2?

Example Setup

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure the interfaces on the Cisco ASA as trunk interfaces and tag the traffic coming from the switch, it can pass along the tags assuming your Cisco ASA has been configured in transparent mode.

With regards to your comment, a transparent firewall is as secure as a firewall in routed mode. Both can check L3/L4 traffic.

Comment: I don't think my topology would be secure. Here is an image. https://www.imgpaste.net/image/Okiri  I am trying to passthrough from HQSW_INTERNAL to HQSQ_MIDDLE

Comment: Please update your question with the image and additional information. Why would it be secure or not secure?

Comment: I need to use the FTP, Syslog, AAADS services. AAADS needs to send authentication information back to IN_PC1, the middle zone is a lower security zone.

Comment: @Ninja2k: we do not create your configuration for you. If you have specific questions, we can help. Otherwise you better hire a consultant to do the configuration for you.

Comment: This is only a practice setup, not a real world WAN.